# How to call a function inside the controller: Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I wrote a function (isCategoryAllowed) but it doesn’t work out how to make it work?
If I move the code to the function (isActive) then everything works.

How to call this function to make it work?

```
<?php

namespace Chester\ShippingCollect\Model\Carrier;

/* Parents, traits and interfaces */

use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

/* Parent dependencies */

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory as RateErrorFactory;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
/* Class dependencies */

use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory as RateResultFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory as RateMethodFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

/* Invokables */

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Collect extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    const PATH_EXCLUDE_CATEGORIES = 'carriers/chester_collect/exclude_categories';

    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_cart;

    protected $_code = 'chester_collect';

    protected $_session;

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        RateErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        Session $session,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        RateResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        RateMethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCategoryAllowed()
    {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $cartProductIds = $this->_cart->getQuoteProductIds();
        $categoryId = array();
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => [$cartProductIds]]);

        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $categoryId[] = $product->getCategoryIds();
        }

        $cat_need = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::PATH_EXCLUDE_CATEGORIES, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $input = explode(",", $cat_need);
        $result = array_reduce($categoryId, function ($result, $arr) use ($input) {
            if (!$arr) return $result;
            return $result && array_intersect($input, $arr);
        }, true);
        if ($result === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isActive()
    {

        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        if (
            empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/city', $scope))
            || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/country_id', $scope))
            || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/postcode', $scope))
            || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/street_line1', $scope))
            || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/phone', $scope))
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function isTrackingAvailable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    protected function getShippingPrice()
    {
        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);
        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->isActive()) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: "My code is not working" questions are not very welcome on stackoverflow. please provide more information

Comment: The code itself works, I just threw it into a separate function (isCategoryAllowed), so how do I call it now?

Comment: Why using Session Magento\Checkout\Model\Session at this class ?

Comment: You don't call the `isCategoryAllowed()`  function they how it will run!!!

Comment: I want to know how to call her

Comment: What you question motive! You have tried to called  `isCategoryAllowed()` from a controller?

Comment: yes, how do i call a function in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not getting what you actually want to do. To call your method you can use it in isActive method something like below

```
public function isActive()
{

    if(!$this->isCategoryAllowed()){
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
    $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    if (
        empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/city', $scope))
        || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/country_id', $scope))
        || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/postcode', $scope))
        || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/street_line1', $scope))
        || empty($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/phone', $scope))
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mach)